# tinyMCE.activeEditor is undefined in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, tinymce, joomla1.5

I installed `tinymce` plugin in joomla 1.5.26.

When I try to use it in admin panel it gives me the following error:

`tinyMCE.activeEditor is undefined`

Kindly suggest what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tinyMCE.activeEditor` gets set when a user clicks into an editor content.
It is better to use `tinymce.get('your_editor_id')` instead. This is always defined when the editor has been initialized.